# Change `sshd` log file with `rsyslog`

Tags: logging, sshd, rsyslog

I want to change the location of `sshd` logging to an external volume in order to prevent filling up the boot volume. What I thought would work – create `/etc/rsyslog.d/sshd.conf` with a directive to use the new log file – is not working.

- Ubuntu 20.04LTS.
- Log file is `/mnt/example_logs_01/sshd/auth.log`.

Current modifications to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Port [number]
AllowGroups ssh-users
LoginGraceTime 30
LogLevel VERBOSE
MaxStartups 5
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
```

Contents of `/etc/rsyslog.d/sshd.conf`:

```
if $programname == 'sshd' then /mnt/example_logs_01/sshd/auth.log
```

The `/mnt/example_logs_01/sshd/auth.log` file is `root:sudo` owned with `775` permissions. I have restarted `rsyslogd` using `systemctl restart rsyslog`, but the server continues to use the default file `/var/log/auth.log` over the new file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One workaround is that you can mount the external volume to /var/log.

Comment: @CharlesS – thank you, I had considered that, I'll see how feasible that is for me.